# Facet based on field or element range index

Tags: marklogic, marklogic-8

I have an xml file like below

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<document-envelope xmlns="http://abc/content-repo/envelope">
  <metadata xmlns="http://abc/content-repo/metadata">
    <name>48363ff1d9e0a48dc9e578f0f4519564628fdbbc.docx</name>
    <SubjectMatter>
    Combination Therapy; Comparative Efficacy; Pharmacokinetics/Pharmacodynamics; Safety; Serum Drug Levels; Therapeutic Drug Monitoring (TDM)
    </SubjectMatter>
  </metadata>
</document-enevelope>
```

I created a field and field range index for the `SubjectMatter`.

My dilemma is, when I create a facet for `SubjectMatter`, it treats the whole content in the `<SubjectMatter>` as one unique entity. But I want to make ';' delimited text as unique entity. for eg: for the sample xml above I want the facet to be

```
Combination Therapy
Comparative Efficacy
Pharmacokinetics/Pharmacodynamics
Safety
Serum Drug Levels
Therapeutic Drug Monitoring (TDM)
```

I understand I could achieve this by parsing the string and adding each one as separate `SubjectMatter` while constructing the envelope.

I was wondering if there is another way to do this, without creating multiple  `SubjectMatter` xml tags in the document envelope ?

Following is a sample xml file..

```
<?xml  version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<document-envelope xmlns="http://abc/content-repo/envelope">
  <metadata xmlns="http://abc/content-repo/metadata">
    <name>2747f031c217f9e23f1e2c1e600ee48cc703494a.pdf</name>
    <context>GMA</context>
    <mime-type>application/pdf</mime-type>
    <file-type>PDF</file-type>
    <virtual-path>KN</virtual-path>
    <id>54a7b5298b5574ea7e5b743a2817d6c5ad723ac4</id>
    <uploadDate>2016-07-13T02:55:00.000-05:00</uploadDate>
    <remoteURL>https://teams.abbvienet.com/gprd/gma/KM/Lists/Library/Attachments/1120/Hawaii Derm 2013 Meeting Summary CSM Ed.pdf?Web=1</remoteURL>
    <displayFilename>Hawaii Derm 2013 Meeting Summary CSM Ed.pdf</displayFilename>
    <Title xmlns="http://abc/content-repo/metadata/gma">Hawaii Derm 2013 Meeting Summary CSM Ed</Title>
    <Modified-Date xmlns="http://abc/content-repo/metadata/gma">2016-07-13T02:55:00.000-05:00</Modified-Date>
    <author>a-gangapx</author>
    <Presenter xmlns="http://abc/content-repo/metadata/gma">US MSLs</Presenter>
    <Organization xmlns="http://abc/content-repo/metadata/gma">Malhotra, Kailash</Organization>
    <Description xmlns="http://abc/content-repo/metadata/gma">Regional Medical Meeting Report</Description>
    <Therapeutic-Area xmlns="http://abc/content-repo/metadata/gma">7. Immuno - Dermatology</Therapeutic-Area>
    <Disease-State xmlns="http://abc/content-repo/metadata/gma">7. Ps</Disease-State>
    <Material-Type xmlns="http://abc/content-repo/metadata/gma">Report</Material-Type>
    <SubjectMatter xmlns="http://abc/content-repo/metadata/gma">Safety; Pediatrics</SubjectMatter>
    <Region xmlns="http://abc/content-repo/metadata/gma">United States</Region>
    <Language xmlns="http://abc/content-repo/metadata/gma">English</Language>
    <Publication-Date xmlns="http://abc/content-repo/metadata/gma">2013-02-10T00:00:00.000-06:00</Publication-Date>
    <Active-Date xmlns="http://abc/content-repo/metadata/gma">2014-02-07T00:00:00.000-06:00</Active-Date>
    <Expiration-Date xmlns="http://abc/content-repo/metadata/gma">2014-01-01T00:00:00.000-06:00</Expiration-Date>
    <Congress xmlns="http://abc/content-repo/metadata/gma">Other</Congress>
    <Congress-Year xmlns="http://abc/content-repo/metadata/gma">2013</Congress-Year>
    <Endorsement xmlns="http://abc/content-repo/metadata/gma">MSL</Endorsement>
  </metadata>
</document-envelope>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For the native use of MarkLogic facets, then I think refactoring your envelope is the most logical approach.

If you want to keep the data as is, then you *may* find this approach acceptable:

Create a field on the subjectMatter element*

- Add a lexicon
- And customise the tokenizer to only split on ';'

At this point, you have the information in a lexicon in the way you wish.

Then see if the tools available in the document abou[t "Browsing with Lexicons](https://docs.marklogic.com/guide/search-dev/lexicon#id_95439)" does enough for you.

- Why a field and not an elementWordLexicon? If we use a field, then we can use the settings available in the admin interface. If we use an elementWordLexicon, then we would register the custom tokenizer. The field option I described does have more overhead at index time. However, it is slightly easier to implement.

Comment: I did the following, for the field

`word lexicons` 
`http://marklogic.com/collation/`
`tokenizer overrides `
`Character Class`
`; word`


It does not seems to work ? am I missing something

Comment: Well, specifically: What is the content in your test? What are the setting in the lexicon? How did you test it? What are the results? I need a bit more before I jump in deeper.

Comment: Added sample xml to my original question.. I am using the Root Collation. To test I did 
`cts:field-values("topic")[1 to 1000]`

Comment: Added sample xml to my original question.. I am using the Root Collation. To test I did 
`cts:field-values("topic")[1 to 1000]`

I created a field with name 'topic' for the SubjectMatter and added the Root collation (`http://marklogic.com/collation/`) and tokenizer overides as ` ; word`

I still did not get the parsed SubjectMatter as individual field-values, I also did using the search options with constratin as `topic`
and did the `search:search` and same thing the facet came without parsing.

Comment: (1) Based on the documentation I linked to, the use case requires field-words, not field-values (the sample uses element-words, but the rest is the same.  (2), the closest okenize overide is actually to redefine space as a work character. This gets you almost exactly what it appears you want. However, the space between entries causes an ugly space to be indexed at the start of some content. Example: "Combination Therapy; Comparative Efficacy;" in this case, the space in "y; C"  is indexed with the C. You will need to use a single separator (;) rather than a compound separator (; ).

Comment: That worked with adding space.. and tried field-words it works.. but when I try to do faceting on "topic" I still do not see the parsed facets for the topic,
`<constraint name="topic">`
       ` <range type="xs:string" facet="true">`
            `<facet-option>frequency-order</facet-option>`
            `<facet-option>descending</facet-option>`
            `<facet-option>limit=10</facet-option>`
            `<field name="topic"/>`
       ` </range>`
   ` </constraint>`

Comment: You have to do it by hand. there is a sample in the Browsing With Lexicons section of the document originally stated. Look throught he docs and at some point you will see xdmp:estimate as part of a sample.

Answer (score 1):

If you want to have separate facet counts for each delimited value, then I think you will have to create separate elements. If you only care to count number of matches for that *combination* of values, then you could build a custom constraint (assuming you are using Search API), and parse them at query time. You would probably still need special handling for overlapping combinations of values, though.

It might be possible to count separate values without creating multiple `SubjectMatter` elements by building an [Aggregate User-Defined Function plugin](https://docs.marklogic.com/guide/search-dev/aggregate#id_53331); however, unless you don't have any control over the documents, then splitting them will probably be much simpler.